# how to go back to original Ethernet settings?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I was messing with my internet settings because it was going on and off. When I tried a terminal command suggested on google, it deleted my wired network settings - this is what I see:

[image]

Even tho my WiFi is still working fine I would definitely prefer the Ethernet cable which is not even detected in the bios.
Thanks in advance if you have any solutions.

Output of `ip link show`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
2: wlp41s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 84:5c:f3:92:31:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The command that probably caused my issue is the one at line 96, however if its not that one is probably one of this:

```
   92  sudo lshw -class newtwork -short && nmcli device status
   93  sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
   94  sudo apt update
   95  sudo apt install r8168-dkms
   96  sudo echo "blacklist r8169"  > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169.conf
   97  /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
   98  sudo /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
   99  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
  100  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
  101  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
  102  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
  103  gksu "service network-manager start"
  104  /etc/NetworkManager
  105  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager
  106  nautilus /etc/NetworkManager
  107  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager
  108  sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
  109  sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
  110  dpkg -S/etc/NetworkManager
  111  dpkg -S NetworkManager
  112  rm -r NetworkManager
  113  y
  114  sudo rm -r NetworkManager
```

output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`is:

```
2a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7c95]
    Kernel modules: r8168
30:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [1002:1638] (rev c9)
```

output of `sudo dkms status`is:

```
r8168/8.049.02: added
system76/1.0.14~1643391291~22.04~78ede46, 5.19.0-76051900-generic, x86_64: installed
system76_acpi/1.0.2~1659568831~22.04~a88dcce, 5.19.0-76051900-generic, x86_64: installed (original_module exists)
system76-io/1.0.2~1655490480~22.04~0217576, 5.19.0-76051900-generic, x86_64: installed
```

output of `sudo modprobe r8168 && sudo dmesg | grep r816` is:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8168 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-76051900-generic
```

output of `sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r816` is:

```
[12499.896230] r8169 0000:2a:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, d8:bb:c1:6a:d8:b7, XID 541, IRQ 70
[12499.896235] r8169 0000:2a:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[12499.897810] r8169 0000:2a:00.0 enp42s0: renamed from eth0
```

Comment: For starters, you should probably include the command you ran. Also, it would be good if you had some idea how your wired network was configured.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion but i kinda have no idea of what that command was, i tryed to find it but i got lost in my search history beacause i have tryed so many things to resolve this problem, and what do you mean by "it would be good if you had some idea how your wired network was configured"?, again thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, it seems you ethernet adapter has been disabled in the BIOS (that commands should show all adapters detected, even if they're not configured) - can you enable it?

Comment: i have been already in the bios and turned everything related to network/lan/ethernet plug on before running `ip link show`

Comment: Sorry, you need to run dmesg with sudo: `sudo dmesg | grep eth`

Comment: It might be easiest for you to reinstall Ubuntu. In future, please don't run random commands from internet unless you know what they are supposed to do.

Comment: @ArturMeinild with `sudo dmesg | grep eth` there is no output.          

@ArchismanPanigrahi thanks for the tip, i was thinking about it but i was hoping that there was a solution

Comment: Ok - then it still sounds like the kernel does not recognize the network adapter at all. But we still don't know what you did. Maybe you disabled a kernel module, we can't possibly know what has happened. All I can say is that the kernel does not detect any ethernet adapters - which is not good if you don't know how to troubleshoot it. 

Comment: Please run the command: `history | less` and see if you can find the commands that you issued. Also, please edit your question to include the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let's also see: `sudo dkms status` and: `sudo modprobe r8168 && sudo dmesg | grep r816`

Comment: Let's try: `sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r816`

Comment: Are you running Pop_OS? Because the kernel is not a stock Ubuntu kernel. Also, it's clear that you somehow disabled the kernel module for your network adapter.

Comment: yes, i am using pop_os, i probably should have specified it, am so sorry

Comment: Pop OS is not an official Ubuntu flavor and thus off-topic here.

Comment: r8168-dkms is built but not installed. I am sure it is not appropriate for kernel version 5.19 et seq. Remove the blacklist and go back to r8169 or, even better, install Ubuntu!!!

Comment: I hope the helpful people at the Pop OS forums can help you out further. And hopefully you have gotten some clues here as to why it isn't working. Cheers! 